# How to connect spark to BigQuery using BigQuery api

Tags: apache-spark, google-api, google-bigquery, gcloud, google-app-invites

I'm newbie in gcloud and BigQuery and want to read data from BigQuery using spark.
I used [Google APIs Client Library for Java.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authentication) and able to connect with BigQuery.
I get the **com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery** object and able to print read datasets,tableId,and tableData

My question is

How can I connect this BigQuery authenticate object(credential object) to spark or is there anyway to use this object with hadoopApi

if there is no possibility than how can pass credential object to newHadoopAPi

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    Credential credential=flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
    return credential;
```

My Hadoop api code is where I want to use my credential object

```
val tableData = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  conf,
  classOf[GsonBigQueryInputFormat],
  classOf[LongWritable],
  classOf[JsonObject]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx @michael with the help of your link I found the solution

Just disable service account on hadoop configuration

```
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "false")
```

and following code will be work

```
val hadoopConfiguration = sc.hadoopConfiguration
//BigQueryConfiguration.
hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
hadoopConfiguration.set(BigQueryConfiguration.PROJECT_ID_KEY, projectId);
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.project.id", projectId);
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "false")
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.client.id",
  clientId)
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.client.secret",
  clientSecret)
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem");
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.auth.client.file", tokenPath);
hadoopConfiguration.set(BigQueryConfiguration.GCS_BUCKET_KEY, bucket)

// Configure input and output for BigQuery access.
com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryInput(hadoopConfiguration, dataSetId + "." + tableId)
val tableData = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  hadoopConfiguration,
  classOf[GsonBigQueryInputFormat],
  classOf[LongWritable],
  classOf[JsonObject])
```

Where token path contain refresh token

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "user": {
            "access_token":     "ya29..wgL6fH2Gx5asdaadsBl2Trasd0sBqV_ZAS7xKDtNS0z4Qyv5ypassdh0soplQ",
            "expiration_time_millis": 1460473581255,
            "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxx"
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the BigQuery Connector for Hadoop might solve your problem without requiring you to write your own low level client. Check it out: https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector

Here's an example using it to connect Spark to BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Comment: thanks for reply @Michael Sheldon BigQuery hadoop connector working for me,but I want to authenticate with OAuth2 refresh token